# Regex IsMatch Issue

Tags: c#, regex

Can someone tell me the error in Regex for below mentioned things:

1. Regex: `@"^(tcm:\d+-\d+)"`

   Input String: `tcm:12-123a6`

   Problem: \d should only match numerals as per my knowledge. Input
   string has 'a' in it. Still it matches the input string.
2. Regex: `@"^[a-zA-Z0-9,&\s-]*$"`

   Input String: `Transportation, Tourism & Travel` which I am reading
   from Query String and comes as
   `Transportation%252c%2bTravel%2b%2526%2bTourism`

   Problem: I think I have taken all the characters of input into
   Regex. Still it does not match.
3. Regex: `@"^[a-zA-Z0-9=]*$"`

   Input String: `U2VuaW9yIFBhcnRuZXIgJiBNYW5hZ2luZyB&&&EaXJlY3Rvcg==`

   Problem: Even with '&' in input, why is it matching?

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

You could also be more specific with a title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. @"^(tcm:\d+-\d+)" will match tcm:12-123 from your string, you need to put $ in the end of your regex to match whole string.

   @"^(tcm:\d+-\d+)$"
2. If ':' belongs to the string, then you need to add it to your list.

   @"^[a-zA-Z0-9,&\s-:]*$"

Comment: ':' is not a part of string. Input String is only: Transportation, Travel and Tourism. I am trying the 1st one though. It looks k.

Comment: It's really strange for the second case. It matches in my case. `Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("Transportation, Travel and Tourism", @"^[a-zA-Z0-9,&\s-]*$"));`

Comment: I am reading the input from as query string. It comes as : "Transportation%252c%2bTravel%2b%2526%2bTourism" Could this be a reason then??

Comment: It's interesting. You have twice encoded string. Do decoding before matching. `string str = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(HttpUtility.UrlDecode("Transportation%252c%2bTravel%2b%2526%2bTourism"));`

Comment: Right. Working fine now. Can you help me with 3rd issue as well. I have added it in question.

Comment: 3rd regex doesn't match. Are you sure you get string in this format? Any encoding? Because without &&& it is base64.

Comment: No. This is the input. I have decoded this message twice too, like you mentioned.

Comment: Then I have no idea. Because `Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("U2VuaW9yIFBhcnRuZXIgJiBNYW5hZ2luZyB&&&EaXJlY3Rvcg==", @"^[a-zA-Z0-9=]*$"));` gives me False.

Comment: Got the problem. When I do 'Request.QueryString["input"]' it truncates everything appearing & onwards.